# Force ArcMap to respect the attribute table entries in the relationship tabs

Tags: arcgis-desktop, relates

Is there any method to force ArcMap to respect the attribute table entries in the relationship tabs?

I have a table named “aaa” which is related to a feature class “communities”, the values in the table “aaa” are entered based on the approval year,

[image]

Now when I identify a point I was surprised that the tabs doesn’t respect the attribute table sort which is based on the approval year or the objectID

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to include pictures of just the Identify window rather than having the important part of what you are trying to show occupying only about 25% of each picture, please?  I think you may also need to write considerably more text to explain what is showing in each picture too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Identify tool always used whatever field or expression is on the Display tab.  You can change it to whatever you want on that tab of your layer.

Comment: thank you Richard, But in my case I need when I click on the relation "aaa" then the four Null values should be classified upon the Approval year or any other filed in the attribute table.

Comment: They are classified by the field ProjectName, because by default any string field with the word Name in it will be used, particularly when it is the first in your table.  If you filled in a ProjectName value you would see I am right.  But I guess the display tab of the table is ignored.

Comment: There is no way to do what you want.  The first string field of the table is all that will be used.  Add an idea to the ideas site to let the Display expression of the table control the identify record title.

Comment: Actually I am getting mixed behavior depending on the ArcMap version I am using.  With ArcMap 10.2.2 I can change the Standalone Table Display Tab Expression and the Identify tool shows the values from the expression I set up. When I wrote the earlier comment, I was using 10.3.  With 10.3 the expression on the Display tab of the Standalone Table had no effect.  Anyway, put your standalone table in your map, open its properties, go to Display tab and change the Expression to the field you want shown and try the Identify tool again.  Let me know if that works or not and your ArcMap version.

Comment: Many thanks  Richard, I am using ArcMap 10.2.2, correct after changing  the Expression in the display tab, then right click on the on the relationship tree and choosing "Sort Ascending " it worked will. many thanks for your help.

Comment: Apparently 10.3 also works under normal circumstances.  My installation apparently had some setting messed up during an installation that updated from 10.2.2.  After Esri helped me to regenerate the Arcmap start-up files in the application directory and the registry, the Display name was respected by the identify window and the relate tree view.

Comment: Many thanks Richard for the good news, I will try it and let you now the results, thanks again